# replacing data.frame element-wise operations with data.table (that used rowname)

Tags: r, data.table

So lets say I have the following `data.frame`s:

```
df1 <- data.frame(y = 1:10, z = rnorm(10), row.names = letters[1:10])
df2 <- data.frame(y = c(rep(2, 5), rep(5, 5)), z = rnorm(10),
    row.names = letters[1:10])
```

And perhaps the "equivalent" `data.table`s:

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = rownames(df1), df1, key = 'x')
dt2 <- data.table(x = rownames(df2), df2, key = 'x')
```

If I want to do element-wise operations between `df1` and `df2`, they look something like

```
dfRes <- df1 / df2
```

And `rownames()` is preserved:

```
R> head(dfRes)
    y          z
a 0.5  3.1405463
b 1.0  1.2925200
c 1.5  1.4137930
d 2.0 -0.5532855
e 2.5 -0.0998303
f 1.2 -1.6236294
```

My poor understanding of `data.table` says the same operation should look like this:

```
dtRes <- dt1[, !'x', with = F] / dt2[, !'x', with = F]
dtRes[, x := dt1[,x,]]
setkey(dtRes, x)
```

(`setkey` optional)

Is there a more `data.table`-esque way of doing this?

As a slightly related aside, more generally, I would have other columns such as factors in each data.table and I would like to omit those columns while doing the element-wise operations, but still have them in the result. Does this make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: fyi `data.table`/`as.data.table` have a `keep.rownames` argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO the proper way to do this would be with a *join* - it'll take care of matching the column with row names correctly.

I'll illustrate using `data.table v1.9.3`. You can find the install instructions on the [github project page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table).

```
## 1.9.3 
dt1[dt2, list(x, y=y/i.y, z=z/i.z)]
#      x   y           z
#  1: a 0.5  6.20339701
#  2: b 1.0  1.72701257
#  3: c 1.5  0.11444594
#  4: d 2.0 -0.70715087
#  5: e 2.5 -0.41692176
#  6: f 1.2  0.07033400
#  7: g 1.4  0.45198379
#  8: h 1.6 -0.04762567
#  9: i 1.8 -1.46270143
# 10: j 2.0 -0.92588495
```

`i.y` and `i.z` refer to the data.table `dt2`'s columns respectively, during a join.

> If you've many more columns, you can just construct an expression and evaluate it. You can find many such posts here on SO under the `[r] [data.table]` tag.

---

If you'd like to stick to the CRAN version (1.9.2), then you can do:

```
## 1.9.2
dt1[dt2, list(y=y/i.y, z=z/i.z)]
```

You don't need the `x`, as it by default returns the key columns.

---

For those interested in the difference between the two versions:

> In versions < 1.9.3 of `data.table`, a join of the form, `x[i, list(...)]` - that is, where `j` is provided - here `list(...)`, implicitly performed a *by-without-by* operation. That is, it computed `j` for each value of `i`'s key columns that matched with `x`. While this is a great feature, there was no way to opt out of it. As a result operations where *by-without-by* was not necessary were slightly slower..
>
> Therefore, in v1.9.3+ versions, we've replaced with *implicit-by* (or *by-without-by*) feature to require *by* **explicitly**, as `by = .EACHI`.
>
> That is, in v1.9.3+: `x[i, list(...)]` will first compute `i` and then `j`, not for each `i`.
>
> And, `x[i, list(...), by=.EACHI]` will compute `j` for *each* `i` - which is equivalent to the way joins were performed in versions < 1.9.3.

Hope this helps understand the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This certainly seems the most `data.table`-eqsue way of doing it. While I agree a join is the best way of doing it in general, there are lots of cases (including mine) where a join isn't necessary and seems overkill. Also a lot more code to write than it would be in `base`. Thanks!